# plotly histogram with log-bins

Tags: r, plotly

```
library(plotly)
```

For this data:

```
exDT2 <- structure(list(outflow = c(-150, -195, -200, -200, -200, -200, 
-250, -250, -250, -250, -255, -300, -300, -300, -300, -300, -305, 
-305, -350, -350, -400, -400, -435, -450, -450, -450, -450, -450, 
-455, -455, -464, -470, -470, -500, -500, -500, -500, -500, -500, 
-5000)), .Names = "outflow", row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want a plotly graph with the x axis label looking like
[image: good label]

```
plot_ly(exDT2, x = ~-outflow, type = "histogram") %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = "Title", type = "log"))
```

but with the bins looking like
[image: good bins]

```
plot_ly(exDT2, x = ~log(-outflow), type = "histogram") %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = "Title"))
```

That is, I want the bins to be of exponentially increasing width, but with a logarithmic axis (so that the bins appear to be the same width), and with a useful axis label, instead of just displaying log-dollars